# Unit Test for recordType redirection

Tags: apex, unit-test

How can I get additional code coverage? I'm getting a de reference to null pointer that is preventing the conditional branch from being executed in the test.

[image]

My supporting unit test:

```
public static Id getRecordTypeId(SObjectType objectType, string recordTypeName) {
Id recordTypeId = null;

Map<string, RecordTypeInfo> recordTypes = objectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName();
if (recordTypes.containsKey(recordTypeName)) {
    recordTypeId = recordTypes.get(recordTypeName).getRecordTypeId();
}
return recordTypeId;
}

public static Account_Summary__c getAccountSummary(Id accountId) {
    Account_Summary__c accountSummary = new Account_Summary__c();
    accountSummary.Account_Name__c = accountId;
    accountSummary.Name = String.valueOf(System.today().year());
    accountSummary.Program_Name__c = 'Test Account Summary Program ' + accountSummary.Name;
    accountSummary.Report_Status__c = 'Draft';
return accountSummary;
}
```

My controller unit test:

```
@IsTest static void testredirectCREPage() {

    //Boolean IsNew = false;
    Id recordTypeId = UnitTest.getRecordTypeId(Account_Summary__c.SObjectType, 'New Account Summary');    
    System.assertNotEquals(null, recordTypeId);

    Account testAccount = UnitTest.getAccount();
    testAccount.External_ID_BA__c = '99999';
    insert testAccount;

    Account_Summary__c accountSummary = UnitTest.getAccountSummary(testAccount.Id);        
    accountSummary.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId; 

    insert accountSummary;  

    accountSummary = queryAccountSummary(accountSummary.Id);

    PageReference testPage = Page.PROD_UW_AccountSummary;
    testPage.getParameters().put('id', accountSummary.Id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(testPage);

    ApexPages.StandardController standardController = new ApexPages.StandardController(new Account_Summary__c());

    AccountSummaryController controller = new AccountSummaryController(standardController);
    controller.IsNew = false;

    Test.startTest();        
    PageReference redirectCRE = controller.redirectCREPage();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unit test is passing in a new record:

```
ApexPages.StandardController standardController = new ApexPages.StandardController(new Account_Summary__c());
```

When instead you should be passing in the existing record:

```
ApexPages.StandardController standardController = new ApexPages.StandardController(accountSummary);
```

You should get rid of the try-catch block, and ditch all the system.debug statements, as well as getting rid of the unused variables in your code.

You're going to also need to use a second unit test to cover the situation when the record type is not "New Account Summary".

Your code is presumably failing because `if(types.isEmpty()==false)` is false (no record was queried), which causes a null pointer exception in the next debug statement (`system.debug(... type.RecordTypeId)`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Instantiated the standardController using the inserted accountSummary. Worked on everything else but overlooked copying structure from another method. So  updated the unit test. Thanks.
PS - debugs are being used to isolate the issue. Would not suggest eliminating use of Try / Catch.

Comment: @rickmac You won't be able to test the catch block, because there's absolutely nothing to catch. If you don't know what you're trying to catch, don't do it.

Comment: the catch will write to the VisualForce page: ApexPages.addMessages(ex);

Comment: @rickmac My point is, there is no possible exception that will be thrown, so you can't get 100% coverage.

Comment: There is an exception that was trapped. That was reported on the visualforce page.